# Getting average time in seconds format in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to find out average timestamp the field timestamp in a table gettime

```
Timestamp
 2010-02-08 14:17:36 | 127.0.0.1 |
 2010-02-08 14:17:30 | 127.0.0.1 |
 2010-02-08 14:17:30 | 127.0.0.1 |
```

The following query gives some number how to format it and get it in seconds.

```
  select  avg(timestamp) from gettime;
```

the above gives some random number .How to format this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Overview of Date and Time Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)

> The SUM() and AVG() aggregate
>   functions do not work with temporal
>   values. (They convert the values to
>   numbers, which loses the part after
>   the first nonnumeric character.) To
>   work around this problem, you can
>   convert to numeric units, perform the
>   aggregate operation, and convert back
>   to a temporal value.
>
> Examples:
>   SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_col)))
>   FROM tbl_name;
>
> SELECT FROM_DAYS(SUM(TO_DAYS(date_col))) FROM
>   tbl_name;